# Django Model Form does not display Image field properly and does not Post it

Tags: django, modelform

The look of the File Upload for the picture in the Form is not OK as the button is inside the field. While it shows in the form as uploaded, it won't post. When I look in the firebug, I can see that the field for the File image is not being sent through with the other name fields, so the form never validates.

Here is how it looks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O3lr.png)

Here is the definition in the Model.

```
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

So when Django creates the Form it does it in that weird way for the File filed

How should I then define the Field for File in the Model? Or where is the error lying?

The Form had this instruction>

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'book_create' %}" class="js-book-create-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Create a new book</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {% for field in form %}
      <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create book</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The handling of the form was like this:

```
data = dict()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewStockOfBookssForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` for the form tag? This is required for fields with upload/image inputs, as described in the documentation.

How are you managing the form? If you use the `FormView` (or derivative) CBVs, this is done for you, but if not, you'll need to explicitly also pass `files=(request.FILES or None)` to the form's constructor.

Comment: It still does not show as Posted field. The others do show. Is the Form Tag properly written?

Answer (score 0):

You can save link,this way is better i think beacuse of:

**1**: in image field you save in database.(**too heavy**)but in link way you have too light.

**2**: in link way you can set it with static file way.(**can delete easy**).(imagefield have many problem but link it easy too manage)

I hope it will help you to choose.

Answer (score 0):

> The look of the File Upload for the picture in the Form is not OK as
>   the button is inside the field.

As for this problem, the solution I found is to add a custom css class to the button, an then tweak as neccesary. The whole field span acts as a button, but it doesn't look awful.

Comment: so you mean this is a bug issue from the Model Form? this is pretty bad. By using modelforms all the granularity is lost, I lose control and it is impossible to fix problems. I had no problem with ordinary forms old style.

Comment: @MartinDuiceivic I found this http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#, I just tried it a little and it seems to work fine, I use ModelForm and widgets attributes to make it work.

Comment: ModelForm is not easy on controlling html output.